# Jasper Studio compile report issue - Unsupported class file major 61

Tags: eclipse, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Trying to compile a Jasper Report jrxml file using Goovy language, I got an error on some files.

Eclipse version: 2022-03
Jasper Studio version: 6.19

Error message: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'calculator_.....' Unsupported class file major version 61

See fix in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to **Java 17**, but not the Java installed on the computer, but the version of the **Java plugin used when starting Eclipse**.

To check the version used by Eclipse, open the eclipse.ini file in Eclipse folder.

Mine had:

```
...
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208/jre/bin
...
```

To fix it, **you need to use an earlier release of Eclipse JRE**.

I downloaded the version 16.0.2 full from : https://download.eclipse.org/justj/www/download.eclipse.org.php?file=jres/16/updates/release/16.0.2/plugins

Once downloaded:

1. Copy the JAR file downloaded to /eclipse/plugins folder
2. Unzip the jar (under eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149 in my case)
3. Modify the eclipse.ini accordingly:

   ```
   -vm
   plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149/jre/bin
   ```

Restart Eclipse.

*Note: I did save the old eclipse.ini as eclipse.ini.17 just in case I need to rollback to Java version 17.*

**UPDATE**

With Eclipse version 2022-12, Java 17 is required to start.

I fixed it defining the JRE to use for Jasper Report. Go to Window / Preferences / JasperStudio  / Properties:
For property net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.classpath

Set value to: /home/csimon/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar

Restart Eclipse

Remaining reports with error were fixed by changing language="groovy"  to language="java"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can download and use Jaspersoft Studio from https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio/releases

I had the same error message in Eclipse. Using Studio worked out of the box without error message.